# Does final field guarantee the field values to be visible in a different thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, jcstress

I am using `JCStress` to test for the final variable. I know that `final` can be used to make sure that when you construct an object, another thread accessing that object doesn't see that object in a partially constructed state.
Now I have a class **A.java** as such

```
public class A {
    final int f;

    A() {
        this.f = 42;
    }

}
```

According to my knowledge, the constructor should be executed as such

```
A temp = <new>
temp.f = 42
<freeze value>
fv = temp
```

Now I'm using the below-mentioned test.

```
@JCStressTest
@State
public class FinalField {
    A a;

    @Actor
    public void writer() {
        a = new A();
    }

    @Actor
    public void reader(I_Result result) {
        A ta = a;
        if (ta != null) {
            result.r1 = ta.f; 
        }
    }

}
```

Now, why is it that I see the value 0 in my output? My CPU architecture is x86, so reordering stores with loads also doesn't make sense. The output I get is

```
           0    94,922,153     FORBIDDEN  No default case provided, assume FORBIDDEN                  
          42    48,638,587     ACCEPTABLE  Final value initialized
```

Also, one more thing that I found unusual is that when I declare the field `a` as `static`. I get only 42 as my output, and why is that?

```
          42   299,477,390     ACCEPTABLE  Final value initialized
```

Answer (score 1):

> Now why is it that I see the value 0 in my output ?

These is the case when `a == null` (and therefore `result.r1` remains `0`) in your `reader()` method.

> when I declare the field a as static. I get only 42 as my output, and why is that?

You annotated `FinalField` with `@State`, therefore JCStress creates a new instance of `FinalField` for every execution.
If `a` is an instance field in `FinalField`, then it is `null` initially in every execution.
If `a` is a static field in `FinalField`, then it is shared across all executions and is `null` only in the first execution.

Comment: So, is there a way to test whether the variable f is 0 (i.e partially initialized), I removed the final from the class A. I only get 42.

Answer (score 1):

Another answer already explained why you have problems with `0` and `static`.
But even with these problems fixed it could be difficult to reproduce partial initialization.
So I would recommend you to take a look at the JCStress source code: it contains samples, and one of them ([JMMSample_06_Finals](https://github.com/openjdk/jcstress/blob/master/jcstress-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jcstress/samples/JMMSample_06_Finals.java)) already does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The explanation is really easy. What is the *default* value of `result.r1`? What type is `r1`? It's an `int`, and a *default* value for a `int` is `zero`. So when this `if (ta != null)` does not happen, meaning `ta` is `null`, your code will do nothing. That "nothing" translates into leaving `r1` to its default value - that is (you already know by now) `zero`. So when `ta == null` (and implicitly `a == null`), you leave `r1` to be `0`, though you do not do that *explicitly*.

The solution is trivial:

```
@Actor
public void reader(I_Result result) {
    A ta = a;
    if (ta != null) {
        result.r1 = ta.f;
    } else {
        result.r1 = -1;
    }
}
```

and:

```
@JCStressTest
@State
@Outcome(id = "42", expect = Expect.ACCEPTABLE, desc = "42 is OK")
@Outcome(id = "-1", expect = Expect.ACCEPTABLE, desc = "-1 is OK too")
```

And now your code will never show `0`, if you read `a` to be non-null, you will always read `a.f` to be `42`. As far as your understanding goes, yes, all threads will see `42` once they see a reference to an instance of `A` - that is a `JLS` guarantee.